# Unit test using react testing library to test components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

How can i write the unit tests for my component using react testing library please?

What am I doing wrong?

Component:

```
const ErrorModal = (props: {message: string}) => {

    const { message } = props;
  
    return (
      <ErrorModalStyled>
        <ErrorMessageStyled data-testid="id">{ message }</ErrorMessageStyled>
      </ErrorModalStyled>
    );
  }
  
  export default ErrorModal;*/
```

My test:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import ErrorModal from '../components/ErrorModal/ErrorModal';

test('renders Something went wrong', () => {
    render(<ErrorModal message="oi" />);
    const element = screen.getByTestId("id");
    expect(element).toEqual("id: Something went wrong");
}
```

My login component:

```
</DeviceLoginListStyled>
      { showError && <ErrorModal message="Something went wrong" />}
      { isLoading && <LoadingModal />}
    </>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? What happens when you run this test?

Comment: As a general tip, use `screen.debug()` to see what the DOM looks like at any point during your test.

Comment: I want to see if the test i wrote is right. any other suggestion? the test is right? i don't know how to write unit test. maybe i'm missing 'describe'.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have never written a unit test in any language? I think you should look up a general introduction to unit testing. Unit testing is an important topic so it's great you're learning about it, but StackOverflow is best for specific, targeted questions.

Comment: You need to decide what exactly you are trying to test. That is not clearly articulated in your question. There are many possible tests for any given component, so "how can I test my component" is a poor question. Along those same lines, you haven't said which component you want to test. Your test directly renders the `ErrorModal` component, but I am guessing you mean to render the login component. But that login component is incomplete, and missing some code that is probably critical to writing the test you want to write (specifically how `showError` is set).

Answer (score 0):

Your actual test doesn't render the login component at all.

The test renders the ErrorModal component with a message 'oi'.

Given the structure of your test, the test should not be testing for "Something went wrong" as it isn't the text you are passing to the component, which is actually 'oi'.

Comment: Thank you. So what can I do? What i need to do. How can I write the test? I've never wrote a test before D:

Comment: test('renders Something went wrong', () => {
    render(<ErrorModal message="Something went wrong" />);
    const element = screen.getByTestId("id");
    expect(element).toEqual("id: Something went wrong");
})